# Counting mistake in number of different elements in two strings

Tags: python, string, for-loop, indexing, difference

My code seems to have some sort of error when considering the 'Q' variable in the following code. I know when counted by hand and when looking at the values I should obtain, Q should be equal to 3. In my case, it is equal to 4. Further, it seems like my code is not properly printing the positions in which the characters differ between two strings. I am struggling to solve this.

```
s1 = 'GAGACTACGACTAGAGCTAGACGGTACAC'
s2 = 'CAGGCCACTACCCGAGTTGGACAGAATAC'
P1=0
P2=0
sites=[]
for i in range(len(s1)):
    if s1[i]=='A' and s2[i]=='G':
      P2+=1
      z=(i+1)
      sites.append(z)
    if s1[i]=='G' and s2[i]=='A':
      P2+=1
      z=(i+1)
      sites.append(z)
    if s1[i]=='C' and s2[i]=='T':
      P1+=1
      z=(i+1)
      sites.append(z)
    if s1[i]=='T' and s2[i]=='C':
      P1+=1
      z=(i+1)
      sites.append(z)
P=P1+P2
print('L lenght of sequence:',len(s1))
print('P1 transitional difference between pyrmidines (c-t):',P1,'/',len(s1))
print('P2 transitional difference between purines (a-g):',P2,'/',len(s1))
x=len([i for i in range(len(s1)) if s1[i] != s2[i]])
Q = x-P
print('Q transversions',Q,'/',len(s1),'\n')
print('transitions',(P1+P2))
print('number of different sites',x)
print('locations at which sites differ',sites)
```

Output:

```
L lenght of sequence: 29
P1 transitional difference between pyrmidines (c-t): 4 / 29
P2 transitional difference between purines (a-g): 3 / 29
Q transversions 4 / 29 

transitions 7
number of different sites 11
locations at which sites differ [4, 6, 12, 17, 19, 23, 27]
```

Proper values:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer here was simply my mistake; the code works completely fine but I simply mistyped a letter in S2.